# Drawing polygons with Google Maps using local shape data

Tags: polygon, google-maps

I am trying to draw a census tract on a Google map. It looks like Google Maps lets you draw polygons using longitude and latitude coordinates. However, the data that I have is not longitudes/latitudes.

The specific dataset I have looks like [this](http://tigerweb.geo.census.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Tracts_Blocks/MapServer/4/query?where=TRACT%20=%20032002&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryPolygon&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=&returnGeometry=true&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&returnDistinctValues=false&f=pjson). The "spatial reference" for this data is 3857. But after looking up this spatial reference on [this page](http://tigerweb.geo.census.gov/arcgis/sdk/rest/pcs.html), I still am not quite sure how to go about drawing the shape to the map using longitudes/latitudes.

I assume that this sort of thing can be done with GIS software or command line tools, but I am more interested in code libraries or APIs that could make this possible. Also, if anyone knows of a better source of census tract shape data which is more compatible with Google Maps, that would be great too.

Comment: Use epsg 3857 WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere on your outSR (Spatial reference output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the GIS StackExchange. The library you are looking for is [Proj4](http://www.osgeo.org/node/1268), originally written in C/C++. You can also find Proj4 APIs in other languages:

- [Java Proj.4](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jproj4/)
- [pyproj](https://code.google.com/p/pyproj/)
- [Proj4js](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj4js/)
- [Proj4Net](https://proj4net.codeplex.com/)

Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks. I will mark this answer as correct because it answers my general question, although Mapperz' comment is more practical in my particular situation.